# Laravel "Access to this resource on the server is denied!" error in cpanel

Tags: laravel, cpanel

I am using latest laravel version on my server. Everything works fine on localhost. But, now I have to host my project, I am getting 403 error when I try to add packages through cms. Again, cms works fine for other things. eg, I can add country and edit or delete them. But, when I try to add new package, it fails with 403 error. I don't know what to do from this point. What is happening?

Comment: Do you solve it?

Comment: No. Its still unsolved.